# Installing Ansicon in win7, with nVidia card, and How to set the environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I get **Ruby Interpreter (CUI) 1.9.3p1392 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working**, after Installing the Ansicon

And I followed the instruction here(https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/issues/35), to disable the Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun.

And this make my command line back to life (Thanks god!)

In the link above, it says that

> Are you using NVIDIA? Try adding ANSICON_EXC=nvd3d9wrap.dll to your environment. Don't know why uninstall wouldn't work, sorry (works fine for me in XP & VIsta, both 32-bit).

But I'm in win7, and Im not quite familiar with setting environment variables.
Could you please tell me how do I resolve the Stop Working problem( and possibly, how to set the environment variables?)

Or, this there other solutions(Besides ANSICON) to coloer the command line in Win 7?

Comment: Have you looked at the `win32console` gem? It should allow you to do just this.

Comment: but isn't this gem DEPRECATED? I thought using it would not be preferable

Answer (score 1):

What i did after getting that error was copying the ansicon folder to the desktop [or whatever folder you might prefer] and launching ansicon directly from there.

That way i dont have ansicon meddling with my path or any other environment variable and i can get the colored output just the same. its just one shortcut or a "pin this item to task bar" and BAM! ready to test.